# TSQL Conditional Where Based on Another Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that contains a simple query like below. The query pulls down all the bids that have been submitted on a job.

I need to add in an additional piece to the `WHERE` clause however.

There is a second table called `Admins` and a field within the table called `employeeID`. If the employees ID that's being passed to the stored procedure exists in `Admins` it will pull down all bids. If they do not exist in `Admins` it will only pull down bids where `b.actor = @employee`.

In short, if `@employee` exists in `Admin`, leave the where clause how it is (pulling down all information for the requestID. However if they are not in that table, need to add in `AND b.actor = @employee`

```
SELECT b.bidID ,
       b.requestID ,
       b.notes ,
       b.team ,
       b.devDays ,
       b.complexity ,
       b.estimatedCost ,
       b.actor ,
       b.status,
       REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), b.timestamp, 106), ' ', '-') AS timestamp,
       e.PreferredName AS bidderFirstName,
       e.LastName AS bidderLastName,
       e.NTID AS bidderNTID
FROM dbo.BS_ToolRequests_Bids AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable AS e
ON b.actor = e.QID
WHERE b.requestID = t.requestID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('bids')
```

How can I go about doing this? The code above is a sub select in a larger query but need to add some type of condition to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add an `OR` clause to your existing `WHERE` clause?

```
WHERE 
  AND (   EXISTS(SELECT 'f' FROM Admins WHERE employeeid = @employeeid)
       OR b.actor = @employeeid
      )
```

Comment: That's perfect actually, didn't knows `exists` could be used within the `AND` section. Will accept it shortly.